# Laravel, catch the error after Validation

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Laravel 5.1 I have this code:

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
    'name' => 'required|max:255',
    'file' => 'required|max:2000',
]);
if ($validator->fails()) {
    // do something depending the error before returning and redirect
    if (name not present) {
      my code for this
    }

    if (file larger than 2000) {
      my code for this
    }

    return redirect()
    ->back()
    ->withErrors($validator)
    ->withInput();
}
```

So, if the `name` is not present, I need to run some code, and if the `file` is larger than 2000, another one and so on.

How can I catch which rule did fail?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pretty simple actually. In the same way that `$errors` is globally passed to the frontend, and has the method `has()`, you can check the error in the `Controller` before redirecting:

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
  'name' => 'required|max:255',
  'file' => 'required|max:2000',
]);
if ($validator->fails()) {
  // do something depending the error before returning and redirect
  if($validator->errors()->has('name')){
    // Do whatever for `name` issue.
  }

  if($validator->errors()->has('file')){
    // Do whatever for `file` issue.
  }

  return back()
  ->withErrors($validator)
  ->withInput(); // Don't need `redirect()->back()`, `back()` is enough.
}
```

Note, this will catch both the `required` and `max` rules. To check individual rules, you can use the `failed()` method in conjunction with `isset()`:

```
if ($validator->fails()) {
  $failedValidation = $validator->failed();
  if(isset($failedValidation['name']['Max'])){
    ...
  }

  if(isset($failedValidation['file']['Max'])){
    ...
  }
  ...
}
```

Comment: Like a charm. I was reading this: https://laravel.com/api/5.1/Illuminate/Validation/Validator.html#method_invalid trying to use that method